# if statement that distinguishes between two values that are not 0

Tags: php, if-statement

This is part of a much larger block of code, however all else works properly outside of this chunk.
I have two columns in mysql db, "price" and "lease". The default value for "price" and "lease" in the db is 0. I am trying to use an if statement to say when the price is not equal to 0, echo $price, else when lease is not equal to 0 echo $lease.

```
if ($price !== 0) {
    echo '<td>'. $price .'</td>';
} else if ($lease !== 0) {
    echo '<td>'. $lease .'</td>';
}
```

However, this simply returns all records in the database that does not have a 0 value for $price and that does have a 0 value for $lease. Any ideas?

Comment: Your database layer is probably returning string `'0'` and not integer `0`, so the `!==` check that includes type is failing. You could use `!=` or cast to int.

Comment: `if ((int)$price !== 0)` and `elseif((int)$lease !== 0)`

Comment: How can you tell whether it's printing price or lease? They're both in the same table column.

Comment: @Barmar - price and lease are in separate columns in the db table.

Comment: I know, but you're echoing them into the same `<td>` of the HTML table.

Comment: Are you sure you have rows with zero price and nonzero lease?

Comment: @Barmar - echoed to same td on purpose so the td that would be created would be either for sale price or lease.  Checked db table and the columns for price and lease use 0 as a default, so if a for sale price or lease price is not entered in, then 0 appears.

Comment: @Alex Howansky thanks for the suggestions, tried both of these approaches and I got the same result.  It returns an empty td for the outputted td.

Comment: `var_dump($price); var_dump($lease);` to ensure they actually contain what you think they do.

Comment: @Alex Howansky - thanks. That helped. I figured out the issue. 0 was getting converted to a string because $ is being added to 0 via CONCAT('$',FORMAT(price, 0)) AS price for both price and lease in my mySQL query. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Ah yeah... don't do that. Formatting belongs in the display layer, not the database. Use [NumberFormatter::formatCurrency](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) in your page template instead.

Comment: So change your code to `if ($price != '$0')` ...